# raw_call issues vyper

Tags: vyper

I am trying to do a swap using quickswap on polygon network with my contract below.
After deploying my contract I get this error when executing the function:

```
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }
```

What is stopping me from successfully swapping using the vyper contract code?

Input arguments:

```
amountIn = 5000000
tokenIn = '0x8f3Cf7ad23Cd3CaDbD9735AFf958023239c6A063'
tokenOut = '0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270'
```

vyper contract:

```
from vyper.interfaces import ERC20

interface UniswapV2Router02:
    def swapExactTokensForTokens(amountIn: uint256, amountOutMin: uint256, path: address[3], to: address, deadline: uint256) -> uint256[3]: nonpayable


QuickSwap: constant(address) = 0xa5E0829CaCEd8fFDD4De3c43696c57F7D7A678ff
WMATIC: constant(address) = 0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270
DAI: constant(address) = 0x8f3Cf7ad23Cd3CaDbD9735AFf958023239c6A063
    
@external
def swapTokenQS(tokenIn: address, tokenOut: address, amountIn: uint256) -> Bytes[128]:
  ERC20(tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, self, amountIn)
  ERC20(tokenIn).approve(QuickSwap, amountIn)
  response: Bytes[128] = raw_call(
    QuickSwap,
    concat(
      method_id("swapExactTokensForTokens(uint256,uint256,address[],address,uint256)"),
      convert(amountIn, bytes32),        # amount in
      convert(0, bytes32),               # amount out min
      convert(self, bytes32),            # to
      convert(block.timestamp, bytes32), # deadline
      convert(160, bytes32),             # path[] offset (5 * 32, 5 = number of func args)
      convert(2, bytes32),               # path[] length
      convert(tokenIn, bytes32),
      convert(tokenOut, bytes32)
    ),
    max_outsize=128,
  )
  return response
```